# Put uint8_t inside of a uint64_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm learning about C and I was wondering if it's possible to put several `uint8_t`s inside of a `uint64_t`.

For instance let's say I want:

> 1010 1010 (`uint8_t`)

and put it in a `uint64_t` but at the "7th" position like:

> 0000 0000 1010 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

And later down the line I could add in another `uint8_t` like

> 1111 1111

but at the 0th position.

so:

> 0000 0000 1010 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111

This is what I've tried but there are errors because they're different types.

```
void addToBitsAtPosition(uint8_t location, uint64_t *bits, uint8_t to_be_added)
{
    // Somehow put at a location?
    bits = bits << location;
    bits = bits & to_be_added;
}
```

Comment: In this specific case you can do `uint8_t* u8 = (uint8_t*)&u64; u8[7] = something;`. But such code is endianess dependent, unlike bit shifts. It will however perform much better on low-end CPUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right general idea, but there are a couple of errors in your code. You need to shift `to_be_added` first (converting the `location` value to *bits*, not *bytes*, first), and then bitwise OR the shifted value into `bits`:

```
void addToBitsAtPosition(uint8_t location, uint64_t *bits, uint8_t to_be_added)
{
    *bits |= ((uint64_t)to_be_added << (location * CHAR_BIT));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void addToBitsAtPosition(uint8_t location, uint64_t *bits, uint8_t to_be_added)
{
    *bits = *bits | (((uint64_t)to_be_added) << (location*8));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a union? (If you dont't have to wonder about endianess of course)

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t Byte0;
        uint8_t Byte1;
        uint8_t Byte2;
        uint8_t Byte3;
        uint8_t Byte4;
        uint8_t Byte5;
        uint8_t Byte6;
        uint8_t Byte7;
    };
    uint64_t complete;
}My_uint64T;

My_uint64_t bits;

.....
   //no you could do :



bits.complete = ob0000 0000 1010 1010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000;
bits.Byte7 = 0b11111111;
```

Comment: It could be simpler with arrays: `typedef union {uint64_t u64; uint8_t u8[8];}` My_uint64_t;

Comment: @ Giovanni Cerretani :Good Tip!!

Answer (score 0):

Even if more verbose than the proposed solutions, you may try with unions and arrays to keep you code pretty clean:

```
void addToBitsAtPosition(uint8_t location, uint64_t *bits, uint8_t to_be_added) {
    union {
        uint64_t u64;
        uint8_t u8[8];
    } t;

    t.u64 = *bits;
    t.u8[location] = to_be_added;

    *bits = t.u64;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void addToBitsAtPosition(uint8_t location, uint64_t *bits, uint8_t to_be_added)
{
    *bits = *bits | (to_be_added << (location*8));
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `to_be_added` to `uint64_t` first, before shifting it.

Comment: can you plz explain , why it is needed as here is left shift not a right shift ?

Comment: Try your code and see what happens - that's the best way to learn.

Comment: Because you will loose you data bits otherwise. Result of shifting has the same data type as shifted value.

Comment: @Paul : Sorry Paul but I didn't got any difference in output in with and without typecasting , I am agree with both of you , typecasting the variable is good programming practice .

Comment: Try it with a `location` >= 4.

Comment: I tried with location 0 to 100 in for loop with typecasting and non typecasting , I didn't got any difference

Comment: @new_learner: try this demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/180a941457d98a30 - it fails when the shift is bigger than a 32 bit int (i.e. location > 3).

Comment: Still not got any difference , can you please check how I checking the difference . http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ffda346e321704b

Comment: @new_learner: you used an `unsigned int` cast instead of a `uint64_t` in `addToBitsAtPosition1`, so both functions are wrong. Try running the "GOOD" version I gave you to see what the correct output should be.